# What is the intention of KEY_NEXT compared to KEY_NEXTSONG?

Tags: input, events, keyboard-event

I'm in the process of mapping IR remote buttons in LIRC. I looked through [input-event-codes.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h) and came across `KEY_NEXT` and `KEY_NEXTSONG`, so I did some searching but I couldn't find descriptions for them.

I'm wondering what the difference is, if any, and when I should use one or the other? Or are their semantics open for interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux event subsystem is poorly documented.  You have to know the correspondences to the USB HID usage codes, which are far better documented.

- `KEY_NEXTSONG` is USB HID usage code 0x00b5 on the consumer page.  This is *Scan Next Track* and is part of a group of keys for controlling a linear media player of some sort.
- `KEY_NEXT` is USB HID usage code 0x01a3 on the consumer page.  This is *Next Task/Application* and is part of a group of keys for interfacing with some kind of application launcher.

## Further reading

- "[Consumer Page: Transport Controls](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf#page=88)". *Universal Serial Bus: HID Usage Tables*.  1.12.  USB Implementors' Forum.  2004-10-28. pp. 88 et seq.
- "[Consumer Page: Application Launch Buttons](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf#page=94)". *Universal Serial Bus: HID Usage Tables*.  1.12.  USB Implementors' Forum.  2004-10-28. pp. 94 et seq.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have found this in a hundred years.